# Is there a way to group documents by an object field in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, group-by, aggregation-framework

I am having difficulty in grouping documents by a sub-document field.My collection is this:

```
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("60dd2747d46aed2e45ec00bf"),
      "orderId": "1a91ab563a51",
      "customerId": "4jnxZbW",
      "zoneInfo": {
        "countryId": "ff17432e9",
        "cityId": "86656f4174c",
        "townId": "188a8707d67",
        "ucId": "aabb0b99c17"
      },
      "createdByUser": "4jQ3xZbW",
      "orderTotalAmount": 5412,
      "createdAt": ISODate("2021-07-11T06:24:07.237Z"),
      "updatedAt": ISODate("2021-07-11T06:24:07.301Z"),
      "_class": "com.bazaar.api.metrics.model.Order"
    }
```

I want to fetch all the records of July for all uc of zoneInfo object( group by zoneInfo.ucId),summing the orderTotalAmount as well as counting the number of documents for each group.The query I have written is not grouping the records correctly:

```
db.order.aggregate( [   

        {
            $match: {   
                createdAt:  { $gte: new ISODate("2021-07-01"), $lt: new ISODate("2021-07-30") }

            }
        },
        {   
            $project : {
                 "ucId" : "$zoneInfo.ucId",
                 "orderTotalAmount":1
             }
 
        },
        {
            "$group": {"_id": {"ucId": "$ucId",totalOrders: { $sum: 1},totalGmv: { $sum: "$orderTotalAmount" }, }   }
        },
              {$sort:{"totalOrders":-1}}
    ]   )
```

Comment: You want to group by what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put totalOrders and totalGmv outside the _id field as grouping will happen by _id, `"$group": {"_id": "$ucId",totalOrders: { $sum: 1},totalGmv: { $sum: "$orderTotalAmount" }, }`

```
db.order.aggregate( [   

        {
            $match: {   
                createdAt:  { $gte: new ISODate("2021-07-01"), $lt: new ISODate("2021-07-30") }

            }
        },
        {   
            $project : {
                 "ucId" : "$zoneInfo.ucId",
                 "orderTotalAmount":1
             }
 
        },
        {
            "$group": {"_id": "$ucId",totalOrders: { $sum: 1},totalGmv: { $sum: "$orderTotalAmount" }, }   
        }
        ,
              {$sort:{"totalOrders":-1}}
    ]   )
```